# Teams Error "Login_hint is Duplicated" AADSTS9000411

Tags: login, microsoft-teams

When ever the user tries to log into Teams she gets the error above.  I saw a post for this but the solution didn't work.  I have tried clearing out the Cache and uninstalled and reinstalled Teams.  The only way it works is running the App from Portal.office.com.  Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] and post the solution you already tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clear everything for teams in your credential manager.
This worked perfect for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it appears to work:

Uninstall again and remove files from the following locations:

- %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Teams
- %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\TeamsMeetingsAddin
- %AppData%\Microsoft\Teams
- %LocalAppData%\SquirrelTemp

Reinstall